# How to determine if string cotains one group of digits in the end

Tags: java, regex, string

Currently I am struggling with an address normalization problem. At the beginning, `ul = street`. In my country in most scenario occurs streets with format like `"ul. Marii Skłodowskiej-Curie"` without number on the end of street but in specific situation occurs streets like "ul. Dywizjonu 303" where 303 is not a house number.

I have an address dictionary where I need to check if street exists. First example is pretty easy to validate because i remove all digits from the end of string and compare result string with dictionary but on the other hand in second example if I will remove all digits from the end of string i will get "ul. Dywizjonu" without 303 which is integrated with street in normal way.

My question is, is it possible to get rid of redundant digits and characters from the end of string and get last pair or single digit from string:

For instance:

"ul. Warszawska 150 12/45" -> separated result 150 and ul. Warszawska

"ul. Warszawska 17/19" -> separated result 17 and ul. Warszawska

"ul. Lipca 80r. 90" -> separated result 90 and ul. Lipca 80r.

"ul. Warszawska 14 10/120/2b" -> separated result 14 and ul. Warszawska

Currently I removed all redundant multi whitespaces from string and splitted by whitespace but i completely don't know what I suppose to do next to get a desirable result like above.

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: 1. Split on space. 2. Check to see if the last two array entries contain a digit: If both contain a digit, trash the last entry. If only the last entry contains a digit split on "/". Keep the first entry. Trash rest. If I understand you correctly.

Comment: What's the rule behind knowing whether a number is part of the street name or not? Why is the 303 part of `ul. Dywizjonu 303` but the 14 not part of `ul. Warszawska` ? My gut feeling is that you would have to add tokens to the searched street name until it gets a match in your streets list

Answer (score 0):

1. Split on `" "` space.
2. Check to see if last two entries have digits.

   a. Both have digit(s): check the last entry for `/` slash.

   ```
   i. has slash: rebuild the string without the last entry.<br>
   ii. don't have slash: rebuild the complete string.<br>
   ```

   b. The last entry has digit(s): split on the `/` and rebuild the sting without the second entry of the split on `/`.

**Code**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaApplication91
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO code application logic here
        List<String> results = new ArrayList();

        String data = "ul. Warszawska 150 12/45\n"
                + "ul. Warszawska 17/19\n"
                + "ul. Lipca 80r. 90\n"
                + "ul. Warszawska 14 10/120/2b";

        List<String> lines = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(data.split("\n")));

        for (String line : lines) {
            String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");
            if (containsDigit(splitLine[splitLine.length - 1]) && containsDigit(splitLine[splitLine.length - 2])) {
                if (!splitLine[splitLine.length - 1].contains("/")) {
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    for (int i = 0; i < splitLine.length; i++) {
                        stringBuilder.append(splitLine[i]).append(" ");
                    }

                    results.add(stringBuilder.toString().trim());
                }
                else {
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    for (int i = 0; i < splitLine.length - 1; i++) {
                        stringBuilder.append(splitLine[i]).append(" ");
                    }

                    results.add(stringBuilder.toString().trim());
                }
            }
            else if (containsDigit(splitLine[splitLine.length - 1])) {
                String[] splitNumber = splitLine[splitLine.length - 1].split("/");

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < splitLine.length - 1; i++) {
                    stringBuilder.append(splitLine[i]).append(" ");
                }
                stringBuilder.append(splitNumber[0]);

                results.add(stringBuilder.toString());
            }
            else {
                //handle other cases
            }
        }

        results.forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    static boolean containsDigit(String string)
    {
        return string.matches(".*\\d+.*");
    }
}
```

**Results**

```
ul. Warszawska 150
ul. Warszawska 17
ul. Lipca 80r. 90
ul. Warszawska 14
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```